# How to get dual booting to work when using burg and two hard drives?

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, windows

I have arch linux on one 250GB hard drive and windows 7 on another. I can boot into ArchLinux just fine, and I can boot into windows if I unplug the hard drive with Arch. But when I boot with both plugged in, I get the option of either linux or windows and when I choose windows I nothing happens. Now I know the problem is that the Windows hard drive needs to be tricked into thinking it is the primary hard drive. But I don't know how to do this using burg.

So what do i need to edit to make this happen?

Comment: Posting your current burg config would help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to do a disk `map` just like you would in grub to swap drives. Windows gets confused when it normally boots up as the primary drive and then suddenly it's number two but still being booted too. In grub you would do this:

```
title Windows
    rootnoverify (hd1,0)
    map (hd0) (hd1)
    map (hd1) (hd0)
    chainloader +1
```

It looks like there is a similar command in burg, but the syntax is different. Perhaps something like this:

```
 map (hd1,1)/disk.dsk (hd0)
```

...but that is untested and found on a series of posts in Chinese on equivalent grub configurations. However in burg there is also `drivemap` which may be what you need. Try adding this to your configuration.

```
drivemap -s (hd1) ${root}
ntldr /ntldr
```

Comment: Does it matter where it comes in the configuration? Like before or after the setroot?

Comment: I would imagine the drivemap should come before the setroot but it might not matter. I'm struggling with burg docs here. Of course the ntldr line needs to be last.

Comment: Adding that removed Windows from the options when  burg came up.

Comment: Well then. At least we know you're editing the right config file. Errr... is hd1 actually your Windows drive? What do you get with an `ls`?

Comment: yeah it's hd1, hd0 is linux. An ls where?

Comment: ...from the burg console. It should show you a list of drives. Also did you try the drivemap/setroot in a different order?

Comment: (hd0) (hd0, gpt5)<-- 4 more with gpt4-1
(boot) (boot, gpt5) <-- same thing
(hd1)

--Also typing exit in the burg console boots windows...

Comment: Can you choose Linux and boot to that too? If so I think we just have stuff in all the wrong order. Perhaps DROP the ntldr I suggested and just make sure the drivemap is inside the windows section, not in the main config. Can you post your whole config in the question?